# 'render' object has no attribute 'GET'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a web application for a uni project using django and postgresql. This is my first time working with django forms and when trying to render any of them for a test run and to figure out the views the render fails with the above error message.

I have worked with Django beforehand but this is my first time working with forms -previously, I'd done object creation and edits through API views. I can't find where my code is wrong, but I've tried rewording it, moving lines around to see if it helps (it hasn't,) and even avoiding inheritance and trying to word it as a straightforward form (hasn't helped either.) I have four different forms but they all provide the same error message, so I'm just gonna show one user model extension that I'm not too confident about for an example, in case there's more wrong than I've realized.

This is the code I've got

```
    class JdTform(UserCreationForm):
        telefono = forms.IntegerField()

        class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
            fields = [
                'telefono'
            ]
            labels = {
                'telefono': 'teléfono'
            }
            widgets = {
                'telefono': forms.NumberInput()
            }
```

```
    def jdt_form_view(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = JdTform()
            return render(request, 'personas/formu_jdt.html', {'form': form})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = JdTform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                fono = form.cleaned_data.get('telefono')
                jdt = jefeDeTaller(telefono=fono, u=user)
                jdt.save()
                return redirect('cal_fecha')
```

```
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Gestor de Trabajo</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>My Site</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Sign up</h2>
            <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('calendario/<int:ano>/<int:mes>/', views.calendario_mes, name='cal_fecha'),
        path('usuarios/jefedetaller/', views.jdt_form_view, name='formulario_jdt'),
```

The error message I receive on the debug page is 
`AttributeError at /usuarios/jefedetaller/
    'render' object has no attribute 'get'`

with traceback

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/usuarios/jefedetaller/

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gestor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Flavio\Envs\3dmente\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Flavio\Envs\3dmente\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  96.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\Flavio\Envs\3dmente\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /usuarios/jefedetaller/
Exception Value: 'render' object has no attribute 'get'
```

With this specific model, the idea is to create a user object, link it directly with a jdt object, and pass the fono information with this instantiation.

Thank you very much beforehand if you can help!

Comment: Do you by any chance define a model/view/class/... named `render`?

Comment: If you'll excuse me, I have to go yell to my group partner over that one model he made. Thank you, good eye!

Comment: you can import it through a different name, like `from app.models import render as OtherRender`, but nevertheless, it is a bit "odd" to name a model with lowercase.

Comment: Oh no, I legit thought that was the django convention, using camelCase rather than CamelCase for model names. Alright, that'll make things easier! Thanks again!